# Firebase - refresh a list and append li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I have problem, I'm using a firebase and i'm using `child_added` event.
When I don't refresh my application, elements from firebase to prepend good, but when i refresh my application, `li` elements are in a different order and they are on end of list and between `li` elements i add a `div`.

So, example:

```
myRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){ 
 var newPost = snapshot();
 $('.list>ul').prepend('<li>'+newPost.image+'</li>');
});

ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
 var winner = snapshot.val();
 $('.list>ul').prepend('<div><p>'+winner.name+'</p></div>');
});
```

I want to have:

```
<div><p>win</p></div>
<li>post</li>
<li>post</li>
<div><p>win</p></div>
<li>post</li>
<li>post</li>
```

When i refresh a page i have:

```
<div><p>win</p></div>
<div><p>win</p></div>
<li>post</li>
<li>post</li>
<li>post</li>
<li>post</li>
```

I need help.

Comment: Can show a sample of your JSON data structure? Or the code that inserts the data?

Comment: No, i can't show a JSON structure. I'm sorry.

Comment: Without seeing that, it's hard to tell why the nodes would have to be ordered in the way you want them ordered. Please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The only thing I can think of is that you need to deal with the `prevChildKey` parameter that is passed to your callback. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html